# Could I copy content in host A and paste it into host B using vim editor?

Tags: vim

Could I copy content in host A and paste it into host B using vim editor?

I connect with two remote host machine A and B. I want to copy a few lines in machine A use vim editor and paste these content into a file in machine B.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+ssh+clipboard , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim+ssh+clipboard , https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+clipboard

Answer (score 0):

By "connect with two remote hosts" I assume you have an `ssh` connection from a local host to two remote ones?

There are two basic ways I can think of, and both involve running Vim on the *local* host and editing the remote files in different buffers of the same Vim. They are described in detail in the first two answers in [How do I remotely edit files via ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202918/how-do-i-remotely-edit-files-via-ssh), but briefly:

- Open a file from Vim using the ssh protocol (`scp://$USER@$HOSTNAME//etc/passwd`): `:help netrw-transparent`
- Mount the remote folder using [`sshfs`](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs), then use Vim normally

Whichever of the two you use, you end up with the remote files opened on the local Vim instance (or instances); then you can use the usual Vim (or OS) clipboard to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your system clipboard in vim. And when you copy something it'll put that in your system clipboard and then you can paste it where you want.

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

here is how you can set vim to use your system clipboard. Note that you'll have to do this in both vim sessions.